# Checking for compatible types using reflection in Go

Tags: testing, reflection, go

Although I am aware that it might not be idiomatic to panic in Go, I would like to test to ensure a function panics under certain conditions and not in others.

An example of the function.

```
func PanicOnErr(potentialErr error) {
    if potentialErr != nil {
        panic(potentialErr)
    }
}
```

The following is an implementation for checking if the function will panic.

```
func InvocationCausedPanic(f interface{}, params ...interface{}) bool {
    // Obtain the function's signature.
    reflectedFunc := reflect.ValueOf(f)
    funcType := reflect.TypeOf(f)

    if funcType.NumIn() != len(params) {
        panic("InvocationCausedPanic called with a function and an incorrect number of parameter(s).")
    }

    reflectedParams := make([]reflect.Value, len(params))
    for paramIndex, paramValue := range params {
        expectedType := funcType.In(paramIndex)
        actualType := reflect.TypeOf(paramValue)

        if actualType != expectedType {
            errStr := fmt.Sprintf("InvocationCausedPanic called with a mismatched parameter type [parameter #%v: expected %v; got %v].", paramIndex, expectedType, actualType)
            panic(errStr)
        }

        reflectedParams[paramIndex] = reflect.ValueOf(paramValue)
    }

    return invoke(reflectedFunc, reflectedParams)
}

func invoke(reflectedFunc reflect.Value, reflectedParams []reflect.Value) (panicked bool) {
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            panicked = true
        }
    }()

    reflectedFunc.Call(reflectedParams)
    return
}
```

Calling either of the following will cause the type-check to fail.

```
InvocationCausedPanic(PanicOnErr, errors.New("Some error."))
InvocationCausedPanic(PanicOnErr, nil)
```

However, it seems possible to call `PanicOnErr` using both `nil` and something generate by calling `errors.New` (seems to be of type `*errors.errorString`).

**As such, is there a way to check if the type of some parameter is suitable for invoking some function?**

While I know it is possible to use defer and recover to more simply test the function, I am curious as to whether it is possible to write a general function that can accept any function and parameters and determine whether it resulted in a panic (assuming the function completes).

**Relevant Go Playground:**
http://play.golang.org/p/qUG7OGuIbD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this function to determine if the parameter is compatible:

```
func compatible(actual, expected reflect.Type) bool {
  if actual == nil {
    k := expected.Kind()
    return k == reflect.Chan || 
           k == reflect.Func || 
           k == reflect.Interface || 
           k == reflect.Map || 
           k == reflect.Ptr || 
           k == reflect.Slice
  }
  return actual.AssignableTo(expected)
}
```

<kbd>[playground](http://play.golang.org/p/DuBa9uCk6j)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you. This solved the type-compatibility issue!

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I've asked a follow-up question; perhaps you would know the answer to that as well.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26321115