# Using reflection to call a function with a nil parameter results in a "Call using zero Value argument" panic

Tags: testing, reflection, go

I'm trying to test a function that accepts a parameter of the type "error". The function should panic under certain situations and I'm trying to test scenarios.

However, when I try to use `reflect.Call` on a `nil` value (which can be passed into a function that accepts something of type "error"), it seems to result in a panic with the following message:

```
reflect: Call using zero Value argument
```

I have found the following posts but I am failing to integrate it into my function.

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/apNcACpl_fI
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/WOUft8EZQ1I

**Relevant Go Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/cYQMQ6amPH**

In the playground above, I would like the call to `InvocationCausedPanic(PanicOnErr, nil)` to return `false`, however, the above panic from reflect is causing a false positive.

Are there any modifications I can make to the `InvocationCausedPanic` or the `invoke` functions to make this work (while retaining its ability to test other functions that cannot accept `nil` as an argument - a function that accepts a string for instance)?

Perhaps the issue is in how the function is called?

I've tred things like `InvocationCausedPanic(PanicOnErr, new(error))` or `InvocationCausedPanic(PanicOnErr, error(nil))` to no avail.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the parameter value is nil, then use a zero value of the function parameter type.

```
    if paramValue == nil {
        reflectedParams[paramIndex] = reflect.New(expectedType).Elem()
    } else {
        reflectedParams[paramIndex] = reflect.ValueOf(paramValue)
    }
```

<kbd>[playground](http://play.golang.org/p/IsbQCr32ps)</kbd>

You can simplify the code if you compute the reflect value and then check assignability. With this change, the `compatible` function is not required.

```
for paramIndex, paramValue := range params {
    if paramValue == nil {
        reflectedParams[paramIndex] = reflect.New(expectedType).Elem()
    } else {
        reflectedParams[paramIndex] = reflect.ValueOf(paramValue)
    }
    expectedType := funcType.In(paramIndex)
    actualType := reflectedParams[paramIndex].Type()
    if !actualType.AssignableTo(expectedType) {
        errStr := fmt.Sprintf("InvocationCausedPanic called with a mismatched parameter type [parameter #%v: expected %v; got %v].", paramIndex, expectedType,actualType)
        panic(errStr)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've implemented your suggested changes and they work great. However, I had just come up with a somewhat contrived cased where the type incompatibility check would not fail for functions that cannot accept nil. I'm thinking it's because the nil gets converted to a compatible zero value before the type-check is done. Do you see any elegant solution? Relevant Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/qvytaeewtW